# ImportError: No module named 'matplotlib' with tensorflow

Tags: python

I am a Korean student who wants to learn TensorFlow.

It works when matplolib is turned and works when TensorFlow is set aside.
However, when used together, such a problem occurs.
What's the problem?

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your pictures, my guess would be that tensorflow and matplotlib are installed in separate virtual environments.

Either install both of them globally or install them both in the same virtual environment.

Answer (score 0):

In the first image, you are in the environment, while in the second image, you aren't in any environment. If you plan on using an environment, make sure all packages needed are inside. To check if you have a package, do `import whateverpackageitis` in python. If it's not in the environment you desire, just do `pip install whateverpackageitis` in the windows terminal.

So, the solution would be running `pip install matplotlib` in the tensorflow environment.